# How to access array from vectors by time index

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have four different vectors from a measurement, where each index corresponds to a certain time. Meaning that the values "1, 4, 7, 10" or also "2, 5, 8, 11" of the following example belong together. I now want to create a matrix, which allows to be accessed by time index. With time index I mean 0, 1 or 2 in the following example. I hope the following examples makes it a bit clearer.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
c = np.array([7, 8, 9])
d = np.array([10, 11, 12])

mat = np.array([[a, b],
                [c, d]])
```

`mat[0]` then returns

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

but I want that it returns is

```
[[1 4]
 [7 10]]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mat is a 3-dim array (and not a matrix), you should use:

```
print(mat[:,:,0])
```

Comment: Thank you, know I feel very stupid. In my actual code I also forgot to create a vector for one entry and wrote a scalar instead, that was probably the reason why the shape was not (3,3, x) and (3,3) instead.